# portlet:param not evaluating EL tag

Tags: spring, jsp, el, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

Trying to set value for Spring MVC portlet:actionURL portlet:param but for some reason the EL doesn't parse the JSTL. Please see below for the detail of Message.java and MessageForm.java and Message.java does implement equals() and hascode(), running as Spring MVC Portlet in WebSphere Portal Server v8.0 and JDK 1.6.

Here is my JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${messageForm.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="status">   
      <HTMLWRAPPER name="Message_Repeat">
      <tr sequence_class="tableRowPrimary,tableRowAlternate">                   
        <td class="descriptionCell" width="150" align="Center"><form:hidden path="messageList[${status.index}].subject"/>
        <a href='
            <portlet:actionURL>
            <portlet:param name="action" value="detail"/>
            <portlet:param name="id" value="${message.id}"/>                                            
            </portlet:actionURL>'><c:out value="${message.subject}"/></a>
       </td>                                
      </tr>
      </HTMLWRAPPER> 
   </c:forEach>
```

---

Using Spring MVC portlet v3.2.8 and below are the taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

---

**Message.java**

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Integer id;
    String type;
    String subject;
    String receiveDate;
    String expireDate;
    boolean readFlag;
    boolean deleteFlag;
    String body;
    ArrayList<Attachment> attachmentList;
    Integer attachmentCount;
    String toAddress;
    String fromAddress = "From Online";

    public String getToAddress() {
        return toAddress;
    }


    public void setToAddress(String toAddress) {
        this.toAddress = toAddress;
    }

    public String getFromAddress() {
        return fromAddress;
    }

    public void setFromAddress(String fromAddress) {
        this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
    }   

    public ArrayList<Attachment> getAttachmentList() {
        return attachmentList;
    }

    public void setAttachmentList(ArrayList<Attachment> attachmentList) {
        this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Integer getAttachmentCount() {
        return attachmentCount;
    }

    public void setAttachmentCount(Integer attachmentCount) {
        this.attachmentCount = attachmentCount;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getReceiveDate() {
        return receiveDate;
    }

    public void setReceiveDate(String receiveDate) {
        this.receiveDate = receiveDate;
    }

    public String getExpireDate() {
        return expireDate;
    }

    public void setExpireDate(String expireDate) {
        this.expireDate = expireDate;
    }

    public boolean isDeleteFlag() {
        return deleteFlag;
    }

    public void setDeleteFlag(boolean deleteFlag) {
        this.deleteFlag = deleteFlag;
    }   

    public boolean isReadFlag() {
        return readFlag;
    }

    public void setReadFlag(boolean readFlag) {
        this.readFlag = readFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            Message message = (Message) object;
            if (this.getType() == message.getType()
                    && this.getId() == message.getId()) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 7 * hash + this.id.hashCode();
        hash = 7 * hash + this.subject.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

---

**MessageForm.java**

```
public class MessageForm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    public ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();

    public String delMsgConf;   

    public String getDelMsgConf() {
        return delMsgConf;
    }

    public void setDelMsgConf(String delMsgConf) {
        this.delMsgConf = delMsgConf;
    }

    public ArrayList<Message> getMessageList() {
        return messageList;
    }

    public void setMessageList(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the Controller:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=detail")
    public void detailMessage(@ModelAttribute("messageForm") MessageForm messageForm, BindingResult result, Model model,@RequestParam(required=false, value="id") String id, ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Message> messages = messageForm.getMessageList();
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
        String sessionId = servletRequest.getSession().getId();
        String messageId = actionRequest.getParameter("id");
```

When print out `messageId` it simply shows `${message.id}` as value - any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the `MessageForm` and `Message` java class code, I think the `messageList` class contains list of `Message` object. Is there any method in `Message` class like `getId`?. Thanks

Comment: @grek, what about `${message.subject}` does it evaluates?

Comment: @PrakashK - Yes, ArrayList messageList<Message> is in MessageForm. There is a method getId in Message.java i.e. public Integer getId() {return id;}

Comment: @Arvind Thanks for the input. it doesn't evaluate either...simply prints ${message.subject}

Comment: @grek, I guess EL is ignored in the jsp, either at jsp or at web.xml ,check for the jsp property ,`isELIgnored`

Comment: Try these links: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html and http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/jsp/isELIgnoredAttribute.html. As @Arvind has mentioned.